# Linq to entities lazy loading

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following class generated by entity framework:

```
public partial class Branch
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public short CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Ts_Companies { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following method which takes all of the branches out of the database:

```
public Branch[] LoadBranches(int companyId, int page, int limit, string search, string sort, string sortOrder)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new TimeShedulerEntities())
        {
            var _branches = (from ct in dbContext.Branches
                             where ct.Title.Contains(search) || ct.Code.Contains(search)
                             select ct).OrderBy(c => c.Title).Skip((page - 1) * limit).Take(limit);
            return _branches.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

In my model designer I see that the `Lazy Loading` is set to true, but when I iterate over the branches, the property Ts_Companies is null. Also I get the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed
>   and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: You are using branches outside of the `using` scope so it has been disposed.

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong right in the error message.  The context has been disposed.  Either don't dispose of the context until you're done using the query, or don't lazily load the information that you'll need.

Comment: @Servy I agree with what you're saying but shouldn't `return _branches.ToArray()` force execution of the query? That occurs within the scope of the using statement so I don't really see where he could be accessing the disposed db Context.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal It forces execution of the query, but it won't eagerly load properties set to be lazily loaded.  Keep in mind the difference between deferred execution and lazy initialization.  They're related, yes, but here the entire query is deferred until `ToArray` is called.  Even after the execution of the query, the properties set to be lazily loaded aren't populated.

Comment: @Servy yeah I think I get it now. When that returns the `Ts_Companies` properties will still be `null` and it's not til later that the query used to set that properties value is executed. When that happens it tries to use the same context but it's been disposed of... I don't like that design, seems like a real gotcha. I use LINQ to Objects about 100x more than any others though so I guess I shouldn't expect to know the caveats of L to E to L to XML or whatever.

Comment: @Jasen first I didn't want to use the TimeShdulerEntities in the codebehind of my UI. So I have seperated this in a class library. One class that holds all of the methods like LoadBranches, .... Is it better then to use the TimeShedulerEntities in the codebehind and only open it ones at pageload or... ?

Comment: @VDesign I generally only use Entities within a transaction. So I map my Entities to DTOs to expose the data to my application and therefore no longer have the link to an ObjectContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created and disposed of the context during your function since it was inside the `using` statement. Each entity happens to know from which context it was created so that lazy loading is possible.

When you accessed the `Ts_Companies` property, the entity realized that it had not yet loaded that property since it is probably a navigation property and attempted to ask its ObjectContext (`TimeShedulerEntities`) to load that property. However, the context had been disposed and so that it what caused that exception.

You need to modify your query as follows to 'pre-load' the Ts_Companies:

```
var _branches = (from ct in dbContext.Branches.Include("Ts_Companies")
                         where ct.Title.Contains(search) || ct.Code.Contains(search)
                         select ct).OrderBy(c => c.Title).Skip((page - 1) * limit).Take(limit);
```

It will take possibly quite a bit longer to load depending on the size of the Ts_Companies object and how many you end up bringing back at once, but the entity will stop asking its object context to load the Ts_Companies since you would have already loaded them.

**A side note**: I have found that creation and disposal of object context on a per-method basis causes problems when the entities are passed outside the function. If you want to create and destroy the object context in every function, you probably want to have the function return something that is not an entity. In other words, have an object that can be constructed from an entity and has the properties you need, but don't have it reference the entity. In java these are often called Data Transfer Objects (DTOs). You lose the read-write ability of entity framework, but you don't have unexpected `ObjectDisposedException`s flying all over the place.

The problem comes when you ask an entity to be associated with another (for example, adding on entity to a ICollection property of another entity) when they come from different objectcontexts. This will cause headaches for you since you would have to manually attach the objects to the same context before performing that operation. Additionally, you lose the ability to save changes to those entities without manually attaching them to a different context.

**My opinion on how I would do it**:

I've found it easier to either have an object containing all of these database access functions control the lifetime of the context (i.e. have your containing object be IDisposable and during disposal, destroy the context) or simply not return entities and have the datastore be read-old, write-new essentially without any modification ability.

For example, I have my object (I will call it my data access object) with a bunch of methods for getting database objects. These methods return entities. The data access object also has a `SaveChanges` method which simply calls the context's `SaveChanges` method. The data access object contains the context in a protected property and keeps it around until the data access object itself is disposed. Nobody but the data access object is allowed to touch its context. At that point, the context is disposed by manually calling 'Dispose'. The data access object could then used inside a `using` statement if that is your use case.

*In any case, it is probably best to avoid passing entities attached to a context outside the scope in which their context exists since entity framework keeps references to that context all over the place in the individual entities*

Comment: All of my methods are in this way created, I have a class library with one DbQueries class which holds all of the methods like LoadBranches. Is this way not the correct way? Should I put the block of creating the context in the codebehind of my webpage?

Comment: That way is perfectly fine. The problem is with disposing the context in each method. If you make your `DbQueries` class be `IDisposable` and have all of the methods operate off of the same context, you will eliminate the issue with the ObjectDisposedException so long as your DbQueries class remains undisposed as long as you need the entities. Consider the entities to be "disposed" once their parent context is disposed.

Comment: Ok so I will set Lazy Loading off in model designer and manually call a seperated method to load the company data.

Comment: Lazy loading is fine...its just disposing the object context in each method that is causing your problems. Lazy loading is one of the beautiful things about entity framework. The `include` statement above lets you turn it off for specific queries.

Comment: Here is an example of what I would do for MVC: https://gist.github.com/kcuzner/8306451

Comment: Thanks this is really helpfull. I Will look further into this.

Comment: Your example is that some kind of repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

But you didn't load your `Ts_Companies`, use `Eager Loading` instead:

```
var _branches = dbContext.Branches
                         .Where(b => b.Title.Contains(search) || b.Code.Contains(search))
                         .Include("Ts_Companies")
                         .OrderBy(c => c.Title)
                         .Skip((page - 1) * limit)
                         .Take(limit);
```

And I came across the same issue before `System.ObjectDisposedException,` in my MVC project and I didn't use `using` blocks,instead I define my context on class level.If I need to return and use an array (in my View) I use that context.If I need to just update some information then I have used `using` blocks.I hope this helps.